# Check Physical Print Job Success

Tags: c#, .net, printing, system.printing

I am printing documents with System.Printing and would like to know when the print job is physically completed or stopped on the printer. The windows spooler automatically deletes the print job as soon as the printer accepts the print job, and there's no clear way for me to know, after that point, if the print was successful or not.

This is how I create the print job, using [AddJob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj205516(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
PrintSystemJobInfo job = queue.AddJob("name", "C:/test/test.xps", false, MyPrintTicket);
```

I can get a number of properties from the [PrintSystemJobInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printsystemjobinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) (Printing, Deleted, Error, etc) but these only apply to the print job as it exists in the spool. As soon as the spool loses this print job, the job status is always "deleted."

In short, is there any universal, programmatic way I can find out whether a print job was *actually* successful -- to know if printing stopped due to completion, error, jam, out of paper, etc ?