Is there an attribute for C# System.Printing or similar that allows you to see the reason behind a PrintJobStatus?
Is there anyway for which i can access the reason way everytime i execute this, the job status is PrintJobStatus.Deleted? Does it always happen when printing something or is it an error?
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Printing;
using System.Text;

namespace PrintTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                // Definir la ruta del archivo a imprimir
                string filePath = @"C:\Downloads\prueba.pdf";  

                // Verificar si el archivo existe
                if (!File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("El archivo no existe.");
                    return;
                }

                // Leer el contenido del archivo
                string textToPrint = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
                Console.WriteLine("Archivo leído correctamente.");

                // Llamar al método estático GetDefaultPrintQueue directamente desde LocalPrintServer
                PrintQueue defaultPrintQueue = LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue();
                Console.WriteLine("Impresora predeterminada obtenida.");

                // Verificar si la impresora está en línea
                if (defaultPrintQueue.IsOffline)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("La impresora está fuera de línea. Asegúrate de que esté encendida y conectada.");
                    return;
                }

                // Verificar si la impresora tiene errores
                if (defaultPrintQueue.IsBusy)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("La impresora está ocupada. Espera a que termine el trabajo anterior.");
                    return;
                }

                // Verificar si hay trabajos en la cola que puedan indicar un error
                if (defaultPrintQueue.GetPrintJobInfoCollection().Count() > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Hay trabajos en la cola de impresión. Esperando a que se libere.");
                    return;
                }

                // Crear un trabajo de impresión en la cola predeterminada
                PrintSystemJobInfo myPrintJob = defaultPrintQueue.AddJob("Impresión de archivo");
                Console.WriteLine("Trabajo de impresión agregado a la cola.");

                // Escribir en el flujo del trabajo de impresión
                Stream myStream = myPrintJob.JobStream;
                byte[] myByteBuffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(textToPrint);

                // Escribir los datos en el flujo del trabajo de impresión
                myStream.Write(myByteBuffer, 0, myByteBuffer.Length);
                myStream.Close();

                // Verificar el estado del trabajo de impresión
                CheckPrintJobStatus(myPrintJob);

                Console.WriteLine("Trabajo de impresión enviado correctamente.");

                // Esperar una tecla antes de cerrar
                Console.WriteLine("Presiona cualquier tecla para salir...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error al crear el trabajo de impresión: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        // Método para verificar el estado del trabajo de impresión
        static void CheckPrintJobStatus(PrintSystemJobInfo printJob)
        {
            try
            {
                // Obtener el estado del trabajo de impresión
                printJob.Refresh(); // Actualiza el estado del trabajo de impresión

                // Imprimir varios atributos para obtener más detalles
                Console.WriteLine($"Job ID: {printJob.JobIdentifier}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Estado del trabajo: {printJob.JobStatus}");

                // Verificar el estado del trabajo
                switch (printJob.JobStatus)
                {
                    case PrintJobStatus.Completed:
                        Console.WriteLine("El trabajo de impresión se completó correctamente.");
                        break;
                    case PrintJobStatus.Paused:
                        Console.WriteLine("El trabajo de impresión está en pausa.");
                        break;
                    case PrintJobStatus.Error:
                        Console.WriteLine("Hubo un error durante el proceso de impresión.");
                        break;
                    case PrintJobStatus.Deleted:
                        Console.WriteLine("El documento ha sido borrado.");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine($"El trabajo de impresión está en estado: {printJob.JobStatus}");
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ioEx)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error de entrada/salida: {ioEx.Message}");
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException invalidOpEx)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error de operación no válida: {invalidOpEx.Message}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error inesperado: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}

I want to know how i can see if the printer has paper and ink. I have tried sending it to the printer an looking for the error, but i can't continue

Modern-day printers generate an error message when printing that provides this information. Did you attempt to print to a printer that is out of paper (or ink) and encounter an issue?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45700836/check-physical-print-job-success
